# Invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'AssortedSorter&' from an rvalue of type BubbleSort*"

Tags: c++, vector, derived-class, abstract-base-class

I have a program that I'm writing that has an abstract base class "AssortedSorted", a derived class "BubbleSort", and a a class to test sorts "AssortedSorterTest".

The Idea is to create a bubbleSort instance, pass that instance to an instance of assortedSorterTest along with an int for the quantity of random numbers to create and sort, and return true from assortedsorter.testSort() method if the vector is sorted and contains the same number of elements as the vector it was given.

If you read the code, there are things that need to be changed to accomplish this, but I'm not concerned with correcting those yet unless they are relevant to the issue I am currently having regarding invalid initialization on line 16 in main.cpp. The error that I am getting is this

"invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'AssortedSorter&' from an rvalue of type BubbleSort*"

Initially I thought that adding #include "BubbleSort.h" to the AssortedSorterTest class may correct the problem, it did not. I've also tried changing some of the references to pointers, this created new problems for me, so I switched back to references. I haven't had any luck in figuring this out, so any healp would be appreciated.

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class AssortedSorter
{
public:

    virtual std::vector<int> sort(const std::vector<int> &itemsToSort) = 0;
    virtual std::string getName() const = 0;
    virtual ~AssortedSorter() {};

};
```

```
#include <sstream>

class BubbleSort : public AssortedSorter
{    
private:
    long loopCount{0};
    long swapCount{0};

public:
    BubbleSort();
    ~BubbleSort() override;

    std::vector<int> sort(const std::vector<int> &itemsToSort) override;
    std::string getName() const override;
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BubbleSort &rhs);


};
```

```
#include "BubbleSort.h"

BubbleSort::BubbleSort()
{
}

BubbleSort::~BubbleSort() 
{
}

std::vector<int> BubbleSort::sort(const std::vector<int> &itemsToSort)
{

    std::vector<int> itemsSorted = itemsToSort;
    bool swap{false};
    int temporary_num{};

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for (int index = 0; index < itemsSorted.size()-1; index++)
        {
            loopCount++;

            if (itemsSorted[index] > itemsSorted[index + 1])
            {
                swapCount++;

                temporary_num = itemsSorted[index];
                itemsSorted[index] = itemsSorted[index + 1];
                itemsSorted[index + 1] = temporary_num;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);

    return itemsSorted;
}

std::string BubbleSort::getName() const
    {return "BubbleSort";}

//Overloaded insertion operator
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BubbleSort &rhs)
{
    os << rhs.getName() << ":     " <<  std::to_string(rhs.loopCount) << "          " << std::to_string(rhs.swapCount);
    return os;
}
```

```
#pragma once
#include "AssortedSorter.h"
#include <vector>

class AssortedSorterTest
{
public:
    AssortedSorterTest();
    ~AssortedSorterTest();
    bool testSort(AssortedSorter &assortedSorter, int size);

};
```

```
#include "AssortedSorterTest.h"

AssortedSorterTest::AssortedSorterTest()
{
}

AssortedSorterTest::~AssortedSorterTest()
{
}

bool testSort(AssortedSorter &assortedSorter, int size)
{
    std::vector<int> randomNumbers;

    for(int index{0}; index < size; index++)
    {
        randomNumbers.push_back(rand());
    }

    std::vector<int> sortedVector = assortedSorter.sort(randomNumbers);

    if(sortedVector == randomNumbers)
    {
        return true;
    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "AssortedSorterTest.h"
#include "BubbleSort.h"


std::vector<int> assign_vector_values(int size);

int main()
{

    std::vector<int> vec = assign_vector_values(100);

    AssortedSorter &bubbleSort = new BubbleSort; //problem is here

    AssortedSorterTest sortTester;

    if(sortTester.testSort(bubbleSort, 100))
    {
        std::cout << "Vector has been sorted" << std::endl;
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << "Vector has not been sorted properly" << std::endl;
    }

    delete bubbleSort;

    return 0;
}


std::vector<int> assign_vector_values(int size)
{
    std::vector<int> temp_vector;

    for(int index{0}; index < size; index++)
    {

        temp_vector.push_back(rand());
    }

    return temp_vector;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly what the issue is.

`new BubbleSort` results in a *pointer* to a `BubbleSort`.

You are trying to bind a *reference* to the base class of `BubbleSort` to it. That cannot work.

Either you need to dereference the pointer or you need to initialize a *pointer*, not a reference, with it.

In any case you should not use naked `new`/`delete` in modern C++. Use `std::unique_ptr<AssortedSorter>` and `std::make_unique<BubbleSort>()` instead:

```
std::unique_ptr<AssortedSorter> bubbleSort = std::make_unique<BubbleSort>();
```

This requires `#include<memory>`.

---

Or, given how exactly the code in `main` looks right now, there is no need for a dynamic allocation at all. Simply

```
BubbleSort bubbleSort;
```

will do as well.